# Проблема с Release-версией программы

Tags: c++, windows, компилятор

Делаю учебное задание, в котором нужно выполнить программу код на 0 кольце. Делаю с использованием подставного стека.

Кладу в свой fake-стек адрес функции. И далее такая проблема: в Debug-версии все нормально, управление переходит на нужную функцию. Вот скриншот из WinDbg,красным подчеркнут адрес функции, который и лежит в стеке:[image: Ассемблерный код в WinDbg]

Теперь компилирую в Release-версии, управление переходит вот в такое место:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что есть различия в Release и Debug сборках программы, но в Release вообще осмысленного кода, как такового, я не увидел, хотя в IDA все на месте.

UPD:

```
auto kernelImageBase = GetKernelBase();
DbgPrintEx = (DbgPrintExType)GetImportSymbol(kernelImageBase, "DbgPrintEx");
ZwQuerySystemInformation = (ZwQuerySystemInformationType)GetImportSymbol(kernelImageBase, "ZwQuerySystemInformation");  
MyDbgPrint("ZwQuerySystemInformation address is 0x%p.", ZwQuerySystemInformation);
```

`

Comment: Приведите исходный код, соответствующий скомпилированному фрагменту на экранных снимках.

Comment: Добавил первые 4 строчки